# ndk-build error in cygwin

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I am following the steps as in http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/comment-page-2/#comment-32553 to install ndk using cygwin and eclipse.

I installed all the required packages and software, including cygwin, gnuwin32, gcc, make, and android-ndk. Then I created a test android project, ndkfoo.  Once I type `/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build`, I get the following error messages, see the bottom. I am guessing there is something wrong with my path setting, but I do not how to make the change. In the example, the first line from the console should looks like `"Compile thumb : ndkfoo <= /cygdrive/c/Users/workspace/ndkfoo.c"`

Does anyone have a clue where I should start? Thanks a lot.

```
    Compile thumb : ndkfoo <= ndkfoo.c
    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: C:/Users/workspace/ndkfoo/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndkfoo/ndkfoo.o: No such file or directory
    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: no input files
make: *** `[/cygdrive/c/Users/workspace/ndkfoo/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndkfoo/ndkfoo.o] Error 1`
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your make file. Are you using Windows paths there by any chance?