# "no input files" when building with gcc of Android NDK r6b

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, android-ndk, cygwin

After returning from NY holidays I've faced a queer problem with building the projects I hadn't had any similar problems before.
Each project is a shared/static library or an application for Android built with NDK 6b using gcc cross-compiler (cygwin).
The OS is Windows 7 (32-bit), and I haven't installed/uninstalled/reinstalled any relevant software (during holidays :).

I've tried to build the standard NDK sample `hello-jni` - same error occurs.
The log:

```
A.User@A-User-L ~/Devel/hello-jni
$ ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: no input files
/cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/build/core/build-binary.mk:217: recipe for target `/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o' failed
make: *** [/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

The verbose log (sorry for overwhelming with letters):

```
A.User@A-User-L ~/Devel/hello-jni
$ ndk-build V=1
rm -f /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/lib*.so /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/gdbserver /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/x86/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
mkdir -p /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi
install -p /cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/gdbserver /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
mkdir -p /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi
echo "set solib-search-path /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi" > /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
echo "directory /cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni /cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
/cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org -fpic  -ffunction-sections  -funwind-tables  -fstack-protector  -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__  -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__   -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te  -mtune=xscale  -msoft-float  -mthumb  -Os  -fomit-frame-pointer  -fno-strict-aliasing  -finline-limit=64  -I/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni  -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -O0 -g  -I/cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include  -c   /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c -o /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o &&  ( if [ -f "/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org" ]; then  awk -f /cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/build/awk/convert-deps-to-cygwin.awk /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org > /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d &&  rm -f /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org;  fi )
/cygdrive/c/dev/Android/android-ndk-r6b/build/core/build-binary.mk:217: recipe for target `/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o' failed
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: /cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: no input files
make: *** [/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

The content of `Android.mk` is pretty standard:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I know that `cygwin` on Windows doesn't support symbolic links - there are no symbolic links in the directories tree.
There is no cruel antivirus running, just Windows Defender.
I run the build as an ordinary user as I used to do last year (i.e. no credential changes).

**What may be wrong**?

Related issues:

- [ndk-build error in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205862/ndk-build-error-in-cygwin) (it seems using Windows-like paths is the root of the problem there)
- [troubles building Android App using Windows/Cygwin](http://forums.rockbox.org/index.php?topic=28143.0) (well, all my sources are with `CR+LF`, but I had no problems with that before, and `hello-jni.c` contains `LF`)
- [compile ffmpeg with android ndk r5b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204251/compile-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk-r5b) (the problem with Windows/Unix paths, but seems to be specific to ffmpeg)

---

[Update] Process Monitor shows that the cross-compiler tries to access the "wrong path": `E:\cygdrive\e\Users\A.User.ORG\Devel\hello-jni\jni\hello-jni.c`...  
I wonder how this tool worked before!  
More info is to follow as soon as I dig it up :)

---

[Update#2] On another PC (Windows XP 32-bit) which has almost the same set of tools installed (same version of Cygwin, Android NDK), the log looks different:

```
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
/cygdrive/c/dev/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -IE:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/jni -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -O0 -g -IC:/dev/android-ndk-r6b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -c  E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c -o E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o && ( if [ -f "E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org" ]; then awk -f /cygdrive/c/dev/android-ndk-r6b/build/awk/convert-deps-to-cygwin.awk E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org > E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d && rm -f E:/Users/A.User.SURC/Devel/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d.org; fi )
```

For some unclear reasons `gcc` is fed with Windows-style paths here... and this is how the processes should interact.
So the question now is **how to instruct cygwin/NDK to pass proper paths**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally tracked down the cause of the problems on my PC with `ndk-build`.
In short: it was caused by the conflict between cygwin's `mount` and `mount.exe`, which is a part of the feature "Client for NFS" (I indeed have installed it recently along with Telnet Client).

#### More information

I've found a similar problem mentioned in the article "[Building Necessitas Qt framework using NDK-r5b and Cygwin](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/building-necessitas-qt-framework-using-ndk-r5b-and-cygwin-not-fun-but-mostly-possible)" - the person had encountered issues with NDK include paths, which he solved by modifying the scripts.
This hint helped me to locate the corresponding script `gen-windows-host-path.awk` in NDK, which performs the paths transformation (from cygwin-style to Windows).
It relies on `mount`, which lists all drives when called without parameters.
And it turned out that `mount` on my PC didn't see any drives... because it was `mount.exe` at `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/` from Windows, and not `/usr/bin/mount` from Cygwin.
By default `mount.exe` is not present in Windows, and if this is the case then you probably have installed "Client for NFS".
So the **solution** (actually a workaround) is to **uninstall "Client for NFS" feature from Windows**.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. Odd it isn't called using an absolute path, though. Might be fixed in newer versions. If not, you should write them a bug report ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Is the source code file in the correct directory? Check the path printed in the error message. c/c++ source files have to be in the jni sub directory, not the src one.

Also, not sure if that helps, the latest SDK/NDK versions should support Windows native batch files. Cygwin is no longer required (debugging support is still lacking though). Try to build from the windows command line running `ndk-build`.

Also, did the same setup work before (on the same machine with same files/directories)?

Comment: The full path to the file is `E:\Users\A.User.ORG\Devel\hello-jni\jni\hello-jni.c`, so it exists, and accessible via `/cygdrive/e/Users/A.User.ORG/Devel/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c` (see also the update in my question).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the option to update SDK/NDK, because the project is not in the proper phase for that. And `ndk-build` (in the real project) is invoked via bash-scripts, which rely on cygwin. Running `ndk-build` from the Windows command line doesn't work because this tool isn't able to find the "compatible GNU make" (I believe, it is the problem with NDK 6b).

Comment: The missing make could be solved by installing MinGW and then adding its bin dir to PATH (might require a symlink from "make" to "mingw32-make" though). Are you able to open the c file from cygwin, e.g. printing it using 'cat hello-jni.c'? EDIT: Just read your update. Did you set your environment variables in cygwin? it might use those from the windows environment using the native paths?

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help me with solving the issue! Yes, I know there is another `make` in MinGW. I will take a closer look at it some day... So far I'm interested to have my cygwin-based system back on track. I've found the cause of the problem - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8841150/536172).